# How to read data with different separators?

Tags: r, read.table

I have a file looks like:

```
a 1,2,3,5
b 4,5,6,7
c 5,6,7,8
...
```

That the separator between 1st and 2nd is '\t', other separators are comma. How can I read this kind of data set as as dataframe having 5 fields.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'd probably do this.

```
read.table(text = gsub(",", "\t", readLines("file.txt")))
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  a  1  2  3  5
2  b  4  5  6  7
3  c  5  6  7  8
```

Unpacking that just a bit:

- `readLines()` reads the file into R as a character vector with one element for each line.
- `gsub(",", "\t", ...)` replaces every comma with a tab, so that now we've got lines with just one kind of separating character.
- The `text =` argument to `read.table()` lets it know you are passing it a character vector to be read directly (rather than the name of a file *containing* your text data).

Comment: Great answer, but I don't think `textConnection` is required here since `read.table` has a `text` argument that could be used instead.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - Very cool! I had always assumed that `text=` expected a single character string, but I just tested your suggestion and can confirm that it will indeed take a character vector of multiple elements.

Comment: I had the same question and also my characters have "{" and "}" which I want to replace by blank. Could it be done in the same gsub()?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Yes, you can do that by using a pair of brackets (i.e. `[` and `]`) specify a "character class", a list of characters to be matched. In your case, you would do something like this: `gsub("[,{}]", "\t", readLines("file.txt"))`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I also have to remove colon at the same time. Can I concatenate colon and curly brackets in the same command?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I'd recommend **trying** it out on your own, by creating a small example (like the `"file.txt"` used in this example) and then, for instance, adding a colon to the list of characters between the brackets. For help on R's regular expression syntax, see `?regex`. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I figured later that it is a JSON file which is supposed to be read differently. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 9):

#### "Balanced" data

Judging by the way you've phrased your question, it seems that you know that your data are "balanced" (rectangular).

Are you looking for speedier options? You might want to combine `fread` from "data.table" with my experimental [`concat.split.DT` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6873058).

The solution would look something like (replace `" "` with `"\t"` for a tab):

```
concat.split.DT(fread("yourfile.txt", sep = " ", header=FALSE), "V2", ",")
```

Let's make up some data:

```
x <- c("a\t1,2,3,5", "b\t4,5,6,7","c\t5,6,7,8")
X <- c(replicate(10000, x))
temp <- tempfile()
writeLines(X, temp, sep="\n") ## Write it to a temporary file
```

Josh's answer:

```
system.time(out1 <- read.table(text = gsub(",", "\t", readLines(temp))))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.679   0.000   0.676 
head(out1)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1  a  1  2  3  5
# 2  b  4  5  6  7
# 3  c  5  6  7  8
# 4  a  1  2  3  5
# 5  b  4  5  6  7
# 6  c  5  6  7  8
dim(out1)
# [1] 30000     5
```

`fread` + `concat.split.DT` (which is like using `fread` twice, but is still super fast):

```
system.time(out2 <- concat.split.DT(fread(temp, sep = "\t", header=FALSE), "V2", ","))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.027   0.000   0.028 
head(out2)
#    V1 V2_1 V2_2 V2_3 V2_4
# 1:  a    1    2    3    5
# 2:  b    4    5    6    7
# 3:  c    5    6    7    8
# 4:  a    1    2    3    5
# 5:  b    4    5    6    7
# 6:  c    5    6    7    8
dim(out2)
# [1] 30000     5
```

#### "Unbalanced" data

Although it doesn't apply to your problem, I should mention this for the benefit of others who might need to solve a similar problem:

One limitation of the above is that `concat.split.DT` only handles "balanced" data. `fread` doesn't have a `fill` argument like `read.table` does (and I seem to remember reading somewhere that it most likely won't have such an argument).

Here's an example of what I mean by unbalanced:

```
x2 <- c("a\t1,2,3,5,6,7", "b\t4,5,6,7","c\t5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13")
X2 <- c(replicate(10000, x2))
temp2 <- tempfile()
writeLines(X2, temp2, sep="\n")
```

`read.table` can handle that with the `fill = TRUE` argument:

```
system.time(out1b <- read.table(text = gsub(",", "\t", readLines(temp2)), fill=TRUE))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.151   0.000   1.152 
head(out1b)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
# 1  a  1  2  3  5  6  7 NA NA  NA
# 2  b  4  5  6  7 NA NA NA NA  NA
# 3  c  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  13
# 4  a  1  2  3  5  6  7 NA NA  NA
# 5  b  4  5  6  7 NA NA NA NA  NA
# 6  c  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  13
```

`concat.split.DT` will give you a nasty error in such cases, but you can try my [`cSplit` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733) instead. It's not nearly as fast, but still performs decently:

```
system.time(out2b <- cSplit(fread(temp2, sep = "\t", header=FALSE), "V2", ","))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.393   0.004   0.399 
head(out2b)
#    V1 V2_1 V2_2 V2_3 V2_4 V2_5 V2_6 V2_7 V2_8 V2_9
# 1:  a    1    2    3    5    6    7   NA   NA   NA
# 2:  b    4    5    6    7   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 3:  c    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
# 4:  a    1    2    3    5    6    7   NA   NA   NA
# 5:  b    4    5    6    7   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 6:  c    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
```

Comment: The option for unbalanced datasets scales *much better* than the `read.table` option, so the comparison on 30K rows doesn't really show it off very well. Change the replications to 100K and do a comparison with that. Also, `cSplit` has a fun feature that lets you create "long" datasets on the fly :-)

Comment: On my system, a 300K row "file" took 160.323 seconds with `read.table` and 2.769 seconds with my `cSplit` + `fread` approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] a = scan.nextLine().replace("\\t", ",").split(",");
    //do something with the array
}
scan.close();
```

This did:

1. create a scanner to process the file (Scanner scan)
2. scan in
   the next file line (scan.nextLine()) for each file line based on
   hasNextLine()
3. replaced tabs with commas (.replace("\t", ",")),
   so the separators were all the same
4. split into an array by
   commas.  Now you can process all the data alike regardless of the
   length of each line.
5. Don't forget to close the scanner when
   you're done.