# Finding column in R CSV file

Tags: r, csv

I am having a hard time pulling the last column of data for analysis.

```
BlockData <- read.csv(file.choose(),header=T,sep="\t")
```

This is a sample the data (I have added the column header c1, c2 and c3):

```
c1,c2,c3
20170918 045759;50.44;1
20170918 045805;50.44;1
20170918 045820;50.44;1
```

Comment: What did you try?  There are tons of answers to your question already

Comment: not quite clear on your data. Is it separated by `tab` or by `;`? If it is separated by `;`, then you should put `read.csv(file.choose(), header=T, sep=";")`. Pulling the last column can be done using `BlockData[,ncol(BlockData)]`

Comment: `read.csv` assumes separator is `,`.  `read.csv2` takes separator `;`

Comment: It is even not clear if the separator is ",", " ", or ";". Is your file small and you can you fix it by hand? Otherwise take a look at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568981/how-to-read-data-with-different-separators)

Comment: I am able to load the file. It is market data, I am interested in the last column which is the order size.

20170918 040001;50.42;1 

 I would like to analyze that column but still cannot isolate it. Perhaps an example of finding the mean for the last column?

Comment: I am still unable to isolate the last column, anyone have any suggestions?